# Setting class fields and then modifying them in in methods

Tags: java

I dont get to write java frequently and when i do its usually expanding others code so I apologize for the basic nature of this question.  I have a class that is used to test another application.  each method in this class is an individual test.  there are hundreds of tests in this class.   as this class evolved, each new method was cloned, so there wasn't a lot of foresight into the overall design.  Im trying to refactor this class so to make it easier to maintain.

So for the question - Each method has a block of code that populates 2 string arrays.  Array 1 is a list of things you want turned on.  Array 2 is a list of things you want off.  Those 2 arrays are passed into another method as parms.  The problem is that if you create a new "thing you want on/off" you have to set it in each method.  Id like to move array1 and array2 to properties.  See the code example below

```
Public class MyClass{
   String[] OnThings = {"Thing1", "Thing2"}
   String[] OffThings = {"Thing3"}
}

protected void Test1{
   /**Below method iterates both arrays and turns things on or off**/
   turnThingsOnOrOff(OnThings, OffThings)
   /**Do a bunch of testing here**/
}

protected void Test2{
   /**This particular test I want to turn off Thing 1**/
   OnThings.Remove{"Thing1"}
   OffThings.Add{"Thing1"}
   turnThingsOnOfOff(OnThings, OffThings)
   /**Do a bunch of testing here**/
}
```

As the code currently exists, if you to add a new thing (Thing4) and test it in every test, you have to go into each of the 100's of methods and add it to the list of "OnThings"

With the proposed code, you just add Thing4 once to the class property and it will run in all the tests.  If you want turn if off for a few tests, then you can go modify those methods using .Add and .Remove.

Currently , the array of strings do not seem to support Add or Remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `onThings` and `offThings` properties `static` so you will be able to use them outside the class without creating `new` object each time.

Also, if you want to add or remove data from the arrays, use `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]`. `ArrayLists` are dynamic in size and objects can be added or removed from them easily.

Here is the modified code :-

```
Public class MyClass{
   public static ArrayList<String> OnThings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Thing1", "Thing2"));
   public static ArrayList<String> OffThings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Thing3"));
}

protected void Test1{
   /**Below method iterates both arrays and turns things on or off**/
   turnThingsOnOrOff(MyClass.OnThings, MyClass.OffThings)
   /**Do a bunch of testing here**/
}

protected void Test2{
   /**This particular test I want to turn off Thing 1**/
   OnThings.Remove{"Thing1"}
   OffThings.Add{"Thing1"}
   turnThingsOnOfOff(MyClass.OnThings, MyClass.OffThings)
   /**Do a bunch of testing here**/
}
```

More about `ArrayList` can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Ill give this a try now!  Thanks for the response